# Passing an array element to another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good afternoon.
I want to pass **categoriesTitle** to the post-template component. Eache lement from the **categoriesForTheTitle** array.

I get the error:
**error 'category Title' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-var.**

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

```
<template >
  <v-container my-5 style="background: #eceef2">
    <post-template :categorieTitle="categorieTitle">
    </post-template>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { HTTP } from "../../http-common";

let categorieTitle;

let categoriesForTheTitle = [
  "business",
  "entertainment",
  "general",
  "health",
  "science",
  "sports",
  "technology",
];

for (var i = 0; i < categoriesForTheTitle .length; i++) {
  categorieTitle = categoriesForTheTitle[i];
}

export default {
 
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error's description tells you what you're doing wrong: You assign a value to categorieTitle, but you never do anything with it. You just assign it each value in the array, then the script ends.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I figured it out. All that was needed was to add "return"

```
export default {
data () {
return {
categorieTitle,
};
},
```